# How to declare a bean in job scope in spring batch

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

```
@Bean
    @Scope(value="job", proxyMode=ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
    public ArrayList funnn(){
            ArrayList arraylist = new ArrayList<>();

        return arraylist;
    }
```

I have to declare a ArrayList bean whose scope should be till job so that I can get ArrayList bean at any steps in job .
Will it work or not ??

I tried passing this ArrayList through Job Execution context but ArrayList is too large (data will be very large ) I am getting error in SERIALIZED_CONTEXT  Column in  BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION_CONTEXT table because of  SERIALIZED_CONTEXT
 column size .

Comment: have you looked into @JobScope http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/core/configuration/annotation/JobScope.html

Comment: Yes I have seen that .. will bean of type ArrayList will created separately for every job or not .
And will it work for large data